# Unable to login after upgrading to 19.10 from 19.04

Tags: 19.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10. Upgrade was done via update manager GUI. I am using nvidia as a graphics driver.

After upgrade I get logged in but I get this screen:

[image]

How do I troubleshoot this?

I ran `sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a`. This resolved the first problem, but now I am at the login screen and unable to login.

I have looked at this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop):my .xauthority and .iceauthority permissions are correct although .xauthority is 0KB. /tmp permissions are also correct. I don't have lightdm installed.

I have also checked the Xorg.log and .xsession log. Renamed the extensions folder as well as the .xauthority file. no luck.

[image]

Comment: Are you using wayland or xorg?

Comment: I don't know. I am on the default.

Comment: On the login screen where you enter your password, click on the gear and try the different options -- should be gnome, gnome on xorg, ubuntu, ubunton on wayland. Maybe others. There are some known issues with nvidia but I'm not sure if this is one or not: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes

Comment: I don't have a gear icon.

Comment: Should be right next to the `Sign On` button. If not, you may have only one environment installed. If you can get to a console login try `sudo apt-get install xorg xwayland gnome`

Comment: See second image I uploaded, there is no gear icon.

Answer (score 4):

I had automatic login enabled. I just updated this file:
/etc/gdm/custom.conf

and commented out these lines:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=username
```

After this I am able to login. Is this a bug?

Comment: worked for me - thank you!

Comment: Worked for me with path /etc/gdm3/custom.conf (see the 3?)