# Blank Screen while upgrading 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, 19.10

When i was upgrading ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 while installing the upgrades, the screen went blank and its been 15 mins it is still blank .

Comment: Please add more details about your hardware. Is this a laptop? Is this a desktop with a graphics card installed?

Comment: Yes this is a Mac book Air with i5 5th Gen

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+F3 open a new terminal console?

Comment: I would wait... In testing 19.04 to 19.10 upgrades on various boxes; settings - some boxes took hours (longest was approaching 12 hours though I including install of 19.04, bringing 19.04 up-to-date, reboot then do-release-upgrade in my timing..)  Your installation (not just machine) can mean upgrades take time.... If you want it quick, re-install using 'something-else' & 'no-format' is quick -- release-upgrade is SLOW...

Comment: No but is it normal to have a blank screen while installation?

Comment: Reboot and select another Linux kernel in GRUB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 19.10 “Something has gone wrong” after update from 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182415/ubuntu-19-10-something-has-gone-wrong-after-update-from-19-04) or [How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)

Comment: I think I have the same issue, I ran `do-release-upgrade -m desktop` in a console and it was working fine for about an hour and then the screen suddenly cleared and there is just a blinking text cursor in the top-left even though the installation process still seems to keep running in the background.  If it prompts for interaction though then I think I am so out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the advice of WinEunuuchs2Unix? If you Ctrl+Alt+F3  (or F4) you should get a terminal prompt. Login with your username and password, and then try typing 'top'. You should get a list of apps that running. The package 'dpkg' should be running if the upgrade is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any chance have an NVIDIA graphics card and have auto login enabled ? there is a bug reported here that seems to be affecting people
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1845801

I have seen some people report the same on the Ubuntu reddit as well.

There are some workarounds like in the link above or in this post
[Unable to login after upgrading to 19.10 from 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181649/unable-to-login-after-upgrading-to-19-10-from-19-04)