# Ubuntu 19.10 "Something has gone wrong" after update from 19.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, 19.10

I've tried to upgrade 19.04 to 19.10.
Now when I start the system, it loads, but is not usable as the only thing I see is "Oh no! Something has gone wrong". I can see activities though and there are "Sorry, Ubuntu 19.10 has experienced an internal error" and "System program problem detected" windows, but I can't get to them -- it goes back to "Oh no!" window.

Upgrade process was not smooth. At some point the messages were displayed:

```
lvm2-activation-generator: lvmconfig failed
lvm2-activation-generator: Activation generator failed.
```

I fixed this problem, following this advice: [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

This is similar problem, but for me disabling autologin hasn't helped: [Unable to login after upgrading to 19.10 from 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181649/unable-to-login-after-upgrading-to-19-10-from-19-04)

Comment: I had this issue. Luckily my solution was straightforward (not posting as an answer because this scenario was particular to my setup and probably not general enough.) mysql had written a symbolic link from `/etc/mysql/my.conf.fallback -> /var/archive/mysql/my.conf` and the `/var/archive/mysql/my.conf` was a symbolic link to - you guessed it: `/etc/mysql/my.conf.fallback`. SMH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the reason was indeed the interrupted update process. Fixed this as described here: [How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)