# Cannot show ubuntu login screen after edit some keyboard layout config files

Tags: keyboard-layout, chroot

I wanted to install the mtgap keyboard layout, so I go to the its github page 
https://github.com/kenranunderscore/mtgap-layout

and do the following:

```
sudo cp xkb/mtgap_30 /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

```
nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
```

(then add some content from the mtgap's documentation)

After that, I restart the computuer. And the mtgap layout is showing on the options of keyboard kayout to choose from. Everything work as expected.


But I want to change some key bindings in the layout (I want to change the binding from Caps lock -> Backspace into Caps lock -> Escape)

So I edit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/mtgap_30 (replace "_bksp" -> "_esc", "BackSpace" -> "Escape")

I also edit the /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml (replace "_bksp" -> "_esc")

After that, I restart computer, then I cannot login anymore

What I did to try to fix that:

- Boot into a ubuntu live usb and edit the mtgap_30 and evdev.xml file
- I also chroot and run: dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
  still can not fix it.

Can you help me to fix that?

Image of the login screen:

[image: Image of the login screen]

Comment: Revert your changes to start with.

Comment: @vanadium: What do you mean, I revert the change made to 2 newly editted files and still not work

Comment: I see. Perhaps try booting into a recovery prompt to dpkg-reconfigure your keyboard. The way with `chroot` may not have gone well.

Comment: Some people have the same issue, I think this may not related to modifing of keyboard layout setting
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181649/unable-to-login-after-upgrading-to-19-10-from-19-04